# Erlang copying of data

Tags: list, sockets, erlang

In the book << Programming Erlang >> Chapter 14 Programming with sockets,

Joe gave us tow versions of receive_data(Socket, SoFar):

```
receive_data(Socket, SoFar) ->
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
            receive_data(Socket, [Bin|SoFar]);
        {tcp_closed,Socket} ->
            list_to_binary(reverse(SoFar))
    end
```

and

```
receive_data(Socket, SoFar) ->
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
            receive_data(Socket, list_to_binary([SoFar,Bin]));
        {tcp_closed,Socket} ->
            SoFar
    end.
```

Then Joe says:

> the latter version we are continually appending a new binary to the
>   end of the buffer, which involves a lot of copying of data.

But I still don't quite know the differce between [Bin|SoFar] and list_to_binary([SoFar,Bin]).

What does Joe mean by "a lot of copying of data"?

Which function make a lot of coping of data, list_to_binary or [SoFar, Bin]?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any knowledge on deep erlang internals, but here is my take:

`list_to_binary([SoFar,Bin])` creates a new binary on every call: the compiler can't optimize that. All the data has to be copied and assembled into newly allocated memory space.

`[Bin|SoFar]` just prepends an element to a list ([which is good](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html)), it doesn't involve copying data, only pointers move around. It's the correct way to build a list, not copious amounts of copies of a growing list.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the difference between list and binaries

a list is either an empty list, either a construction made of an element (the head) and a "link" to the rest of the list (the tail). It is
the meaning of the syntax [H|T]. In C code it could be implemented with a couple of pointer, the first one pointin to the element or nil (empty list),
the second one pointing to the tail: another couple of pointers. - I didn't check the implementation in the erlang libraries.

that means that when you want to create a new list when at the reception of a new chunk of data, the solution with list simply consist in creating the head of this new list
which content a reference to the data newly received (Bin) and a reference to the data previously received (SoFar) [Bin|SoFar]. This is possible because all variable are un-mutable.

A binary has no internal structure, so if you want to fatten the whole data received in a single binary (second solution) using list_to_binary([Bin,SoFar]) the compiler allocates a new memory space and copies all the data in it.
The same principle of un-mutable data prevents it to optimize the execution.